# Query attributes of extended class in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, projection

I have four classes, one represents a product, other represents an attribute of this product and another two holds the values of this attribute, since it can be a String or an Integer, all with getters and setters (omitted here).

Product.class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "product")
public class Product {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "product", cascade = CascadeType.MERGE, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, orphanRemoval = true)
    private Set<Attribute> attributes = new HashSet<>(0);

    [...]
}
```

Attribute.class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "attribute")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "type", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.INTEGER)
public class Attribute {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "product_id")
    private Product product;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "custom_attribute_id")
    private CustomAttribute customAttribute;

    @Column(name = "type")
    private Integer type;

    [...]
}
```

AttributeString.class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "attribute_string")
@DiscriminatorValue("1")
public class AttributeString extends Attribute {

    @Column(name = "value")
    private String value;

    [...]
}
```

AttributeInteger.class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "attribute_integer")
@DiscriminatorValue("2")
public class AttributeInteger extends Attribute {

    @Column(name = "value")
    private Integer value;

    [...]
}
```

I want to create a projection query with Hibernate Criteria to count the number of different attributes and values that a product has, like this:

```
// Projection query to list the summary of attribute
Session session = (Session) em.getEntityManagerFactory().createEntityManager()
            .getDelegate();
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Product.class);
criteria.creatAlias("attributes", "attribute");
criteria.creatAlias("attribute.customAttribute", "customAttribute");
Projection projectionSummary = Projections.projectionList()
        .add(Projections.groupProperty("customAttribute.id"))
        .add(Projections.groupProperty("attribute.value"))
        .add(Projections.count("id"));
List<Object[]> items = criteria.setProjection(projectionSummary).list();
```

But this raise a error `org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: value of com.example.entity.Attribute`

Answer (score 0):

As your exception stated that

> could not resolve property: value of com.example.entity.Attribute

In `Attribute.class`, **you have problem for getter and setter method**. It may be not followed the convention.

If you use any `IDE like eclipse`, then try to use it for creating getter setter method, which will help you more to follow convention.

Create getter and setter for `id, product, customAttribute and type`.

**As example for `id`:**

```
public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}
```

**UPDATE:**

I think `attributes` will be `attribute`. Please check if I am wrong.

```
criteria.creatAlias("attributes", "attribute");
```

Use the following code

```
criteria.creatAlias("attribute", "attribute");
```

Comment: It has the getters and setter, I ommited them only for simplify the question.

Comment: @Magritte which IDE are you using?

Comment: Eclipse Mars.2, application server is JbossAS 7.1.1, JPA 2.0,  Hibernate Core 4.0.1.Final